# Symfony3 routing error "Error: Call to a member function addResource() on integer"

Tags: php, symfony

I changed default setting "router" in config_dev.yml file: "routing.yml" was changed to  "routing.php". Content of routing.php:

```
    use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection;
    use Symfony\Component\Routing\Route;

    $collection = new RouteCollection();
    $collection->add('homepage', new Route('/', array(
        '_controller' => 'AppBundle:Default:index',
    )));

    return $collection;
```

But when I go to site I get an "Error: Call to a member function addResource() on integer". Stack trace:

```
in       vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Routing\Loader\PhpFileLoader.php at    line 41   -

         $this->setCurrentDir(dirname($path));
    $collection = self::includeFile($path, $this);
    $collection->addResource(new FileResource($path));
    return $collection; }
```

Comment: Does it happen when the file you included in your description is loaded or does it happen for another file? Can you show the rest of the stack trace too?

Comment: As I understand, error happend when kernel tryied to load routing.php file. This is full stack trace: https://jpst.it/FTO1